# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to implement custom filtering in datatable. But I'm getting this error in console:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I have following code:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        return true;
    }
);

var table = $('#checkin-checkout-record-table').dataTable({

    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    // "order": [[0, 'asc'], [4, 'asc']],
    "aLengthMenu": [50, 100],
    "bAutoWidth": false

});
table.draw();
```

What is wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to use `DataTable()` instead of `dataTable()` to initialize your table if you want to use API by calling `table.draw()`, see [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) for more information.
- If you're using newer version (1.10) of jQuery DataTables, it is preferable to `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push()` instead, see [Search plug-ins](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search#Example).
- You need to call `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop()` to remove filter after you're done searching.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push( 
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) { 
        return (data[0] == 'Airi Satou'); 
    }
);

table.draw();

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/1hLcpr3x/138/) for demonstration.

However `push()` and `pop()` methods are intended for complex searches. If you want to search one column, there is [`column().search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()) API method.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.column(0).search('Airi Satou').draw();
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/1hLcpr3x/139/) for demonstration.

Comment: I'm using 1.10.0-dev version. Other table initialization is done with dataTable() and it is working fine. Does it matter? :)

Comment: plus the error is gone now, thanks to that. :). But now no records are shown.
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            return (aData[0] == 'Alina Acharya') ? true : false;
        }
    );

Comment: @Azima, Using `dataTable()` is fine, but you will get an error when calling API functions as `table.draw()`.

Comment: $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
            return (data[0] == 'Alina Acharya');
         //return (data[0] == 'Alina Acharya') ? true : false;

        }
    );
The return statement is not working.
[link]http://jsfiddle.net/1hLcpr3x/132/ 
It works here. Please help me